# Flutter http how to get header set-cookie from response?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have http.post request and i need to get data from header, key of this header value is Set-cookie
this is function that i need to use for it

```
  Future<String> getssid() async {
    String ssidSeverLink = "some server link that need to be private";
    http.Response response;
    response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ssidSeverLink), body: "some body for request that probably need to be private");
    // this is what i tried to do, it don't work
    print(jsonDecode(response.headers.toString())["Set-Cookie"]);
    return some local variable maybe
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try following

```dart
Map<String, List<String>> setCookie = response.headers.map['set-cookie'];
```

this will give you a map, you can then iterate and pick the relevant data